# how do i create csv file for my django model?

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

Here is my model:

```
class Company(models.Model):      
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True);
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100);
    state = models.CharField(max_length=25);
    zip = models.IntegerField();
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)  
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True);
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True);
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True);
    hiring = models.BooleanField(default=False);    
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False);
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True);
    about_us = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True);
```

And I have data like this:

```
    Id: since this is autofield, do i need to enter this?
    Name: 1-800 Postcards America's Printing Company
    Address: 121 Varick Street, 7th Floor
    City: New York
    State: NY
    Zip: 10013
    Latitude: 40.724831999999999
    Longitude: -74.00609
    Phone: 212-741-1070
    Website: http://www.1800postcards.com
    Email: info@1800postcards.com
    Hiring: No
    Approved: True
    Date Added: auto added as well, should I add a random date?
    About Us: Some about us with, many, commas, possible, etc.
```

I need to upload about 50+ companies using django to gae datastore. How do I create the csv file to make sure that the data inserts properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this would work, but I'd write a python function to read in your file, parse the data line by line, and create and save the Company class.  I'd test that out on the dev_appserver.

Then I'd run that function in the remote shell.  It should read the text file from the local disc, and save to the real datastore.